# image reading outputs None every other try

Tags: python, pyautogui, python-tesseract

I was writing code to take a screenshot of a math equation then type out the answer, but it outputs "None" every 5th or so time. Was wondering if this was in some way fixable or if I should just scrap the idea. Thanks in advance :)

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con
import cv2
import pytesseract
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
def main():
    try:
        while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
            win32api.SetCursorPos((80,60))
            win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
            win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
            time.sleep(1)
            win32api.SetCursorPos((350,370))
            win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
            win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)
            time.sleep(1)
            while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
                iml = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(190,270,275,150)) #screenshot
                iml.save(r'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\New folder\my_screenshot.png')
                pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract'
                math = (pytesseract.image_to_string(r'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\New folder\my_screenshot.png'))
                math = math.replace('+', '/')
                math = math.replace('x', '*')
                math = math.replace('X', '*')
                if exec(math) == 'None':
                    math = eval(math)
                else:
                    math = exec(math)
                math = str(math)
                print(math)
                time.sleep(0.5)
                for char in math:
                    keyboard.press(char)
                    keyboard.release(char)
    except:
        main()
main()
```

Comment: Instead of just calling `main()` again in your `except` block, try actually letting the error raise and see what it is.

Comment: Please keep in mind that recursively calling a function is **not** equivalent to "starting over from the top". Control flow will eventually `return` back to the site of the call (unless there is an uncaught exception) - just as would happen with *any other* function call.

Comment: after removing the try line I get error that read things along the line of:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\New folder\bot.py", line 39, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\New folder\bot.py", line 29, in main
    if exec(math) == 'None':
  File "<string>", line 1
    ia)